# Cannot import ObjectMapper in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire, json-deserialization

I need to deserialize JSON to objects and I thought using the ObjectMapper would be great.

Unfortunately the object mapper can't be imported. I get the message:

```
No such module 'ObjectMapper'
```

Here is my podfile

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '8.0'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
use_frameworks!



target 'OTTSwift' do
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.0'
use_frameworks!
pod "EVReflection", '~> 2.6'
use_frameworks!
pod 'ObjectMapper', '~> 1.0'            
end
```

I even tried the Git import and it doesn't work

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I used that and XCode was showing me same error on import statement but if you build your project it will build just fine. It seems that XCode take some time to cache new changes because on next import it won't show any error.

Comment: Yes, exactly. You need to build your project so Xcode will be able to link the newly added frameworks to your project.

Comment: Exactly. XCode take time to cache any new changes sadly not limited to only frameworks :(

Comment: I thought this type of problems will be disappear after Swift :D :D

Comment: i ran into same problem and building does not solved it. So i have to manually add embeded biniries

Comment: @UmairAfzal are you using correct format of podfile?

Comment: yeah everything was okay but after embeding Binaries everything worked

Comment: Make sure you opened the *.xcworkspace* file in Xcode and not just the .xcodeproj file.

Answer (score 0):

I always have this issue when I remove the Derived Data of the project, I get It fixed by updating the dependencies with `pod update`, cleaning the project and restarting Xcode.